# Which unicode font supports all Indian fonts in mPDF library?

Tags: php, unicode, fonts, mpdf

I am trying to write some Indian dialect texts in my pdf, using `mPDF` library. I've tried using these fonts:

```
'fontdata' => [
    "sakalbharati" => [
        'R' => "Sakal Bharati.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
    "mangal" => [
        'R' => "Mangal.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
    "freesans" => [
    'R' => "FreeSans.ttf",
    'B' => "FreeSansBold.ttf",
    'I' => "FreeSansOblique.ttf",
    'BI' => "FreeSansBoldOblique.ttf",
    'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
]
```

Most of these fonts work only when rendering **Hindi** characters (there are some grammatical mistakes when rendering complex Hindi words though), but when I try to render other dialect characters such as **Bengali, Assamese, etc.**, they render as squares in my pdf:

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WZYB.png)

How do I fix this issue? Is there a font which will support **all** Indian unicode font characters?

Comment: Voting to close as seeking recommendations, but [Sakal Bharati](https://www.cdac.in/index.aspx?id=dl_sakal_bharati_font#:~:text=Sakal%20Bharati%20is%20a%20Unicode,the%20horizontal%20and%20vertical%20stems.) explicitly supports both Bengali and Assamese: _"Sakal Bharati is a Unicode based Open Type font which includes 13 scripts in one font i.e. **Assamese**, **Bengali**, Devanagari, Gujarati, Kannada Malayalam, Meetei Mayek, Oriya, Ol Chiki, Punjabi, Telugu, Tamil & Urdu."_ That suggests your rendering problem may be due to something other than your font choices.

Comment: Can you reframe your question to make it on topic, by asking about failing to render characters rather than seeking a font recommendation? But if you do that you will also need to provide more details about your problem.